# Swift - View loading before ViewModel finished calling Service (incl. SwiftUI & Firebase)

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

this is my first time posting on here so apologies if it's not right, I am also just learning Swift so any explanation would be good as to where I am going wrong. I am following a Youtube tutorial and my code seems to be identical but I must be missing something.

I am struggling currently with a ViewModel I have which call's a Service I have created and this service call isn't populating the property which is used in the ViewModel so it is returning nil. I have checked the output of the Service method and it is returning correctly, so my hunch is that this Service method isn't finishing before the View is being loaded.

This is the ViewModel code below. The problem is that the "Fetch all polls" print statement is running before the "Fetched user" statement is running, and this user is then not appearing in the self.polls object when it gets used in the view.

ViewModel code:

```
class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var polls = [Poll]()
    
    let service = PollService()
    let userService = UserService()
    
    init() {
        fetchPolls()
    }
    
    func fetchPolls() {
        
        service.fetchPolls { polls in
            self.polls = polls
            
            for i in 0 ..< polls.count {
                
                let userId = polls[i].userId
                
                self.userService.fetchUser(withUid: userId) { user in
                    self.polls[i].user = user
                    
                    print("DEBUG: Fetched user")
                }
                
                print("DEBUG: Fetched one poll")
            }
            
            print("DEBUG: Fetch all polls")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the View code for this section too:

```
struct PollView: View {
    
    @State var poll: Poll
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            //Profile Info
            HStack {
                Circle().frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                
                HStack {
                    if let user = poll.user {
                        Text(user.username)
                            .padding(.leading)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Date")
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                    }
                }
```

Below is the service method which is running inside the for loop and seems to be completing after the "Fetch all polls" statement:

```
func fetchUser(withUid uid: String, completion: @escaping(User) -> Void) {
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
            .document(uid)
            .getDocument { snapshot, _ in
                guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
                
                guard let user = try? snapshot.data(as: User.self) else { return }
                completion(user)
            }
    }
```

And this is the PollService method for fetch polls:

```
    func fetchPolls(completion: @escaping([Poll]) -> Void) {
        
        Firestore.firestore().collection("polls").getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            
            var polls = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Poll.self )})
            
            completion(polls)
        }
    }
```

I think it is due the the Firebase call being async so the polls[i].user isn't being updated in time, but I am not 100% sure so any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, an explanation as to what I have missed or a better way to achieve what I am trying to achieve would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the output from the ViewModel (I am also unsure why the loop is running twice when there is only one poll, any explanation of that would also be useful)

```
DEBUG: Fetching user
DEBUG: Fetched one poll
DEBUG: Fetch all polls
DEBUG: Fetched user
DEBUG: Fetched one poll
DEBUG: Fetch all polls
DEBUG: Fetched user
```

I tried adding Dispatch groups to try and make the calls synchronous but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Where's the definition of `polls`? Is it `@Published`? How is it getting accessed in the `View`?

Comment: without knowing the details/signature of the `fetchPolls` service it's going to be hard to answer this one.

Comment: Show us your `ViewModel` code, not just one small bit of it.
Show how you declare `polls`, how you declare your `ViewModel` in the views,
 and how you use `fetchPolls()` in your View.

Comment: `...any explanation of that would also be useful`, apart from `print("DEBUG: Fetched user")`, all other `prints` you have are useless, because you are dealing 
with asynchronous functions, not sequential code.

Comment: Have you tried the usual trick of updating the (view) state on the main thread,
     in `fetchPolls() {...}` with `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.polls[i].user = user }`

Comment: @jnpdx I have updated the question to include some more snippets, hopefully this helps

Comment: You haven’t shown where FeedViewModel is used.

Comment: @jnpdx The FeedViewModel is used in the FeedView, it is declared like this: 
   
`ObservedObject var viewModel = FeedViewModel()`

Comment: What is the `FeedView`? You need to show a [mre]. It's not clear how `@State var poll: Poll` in `PollView` is connected to any of that.

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct is the view model already you don't need an object for it. Maybe find a better Youtuber?

Comment: @malhal But isn’t MVVM a viable architecture within Swift UI?

Comment: @jnpdx My feed view used the FeedViewModel like this
`@ObservedObject var viewModel = FeedViewModel()` and then the FeedView uses the PollView like this 
```ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(viewModel.polls) { poll in
                            PollView(poll: poll)
                                .padding(5)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You should be using `@StateObject`, not `@ObservedObject`

Comment: @DJ_JONES no, MVVM is not compatible with SwiftUI because it already solves the same problem, just learn the `View` struct!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your view file, but your are using a closure (arrow function) to notify you when data arrives. So you can create a condicional structure in your view file, if data didn't arrive yet, you show a progress bar, else, you show the data in the screen without problems.

I don't know if this will help you but maybe is going to.